# Excel crashes on insert copied rows running from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, insert, crash

I am running the below code regularly, and it generally works fine. 
However, after certain operations the Rows.Insert operation claims to fail immediately after successfully inserting the rows in question from the clipboard (but still goes to the insert row of code on Debug). This does not happen every time I execute these commands, but is much more likely after doing them.

Operations that cause subsequent code failure include copy-paste, deleting rows, hiding/unhiding rows, and undoing any of the above. Save, close, reopen allows the code to run successfully again.

The failure is often catastrophic for Excel: it sometimes gives debug message, then hangs completely - screenupdating appears to be false, but any attempt to turn it back on fails, and the cursor turns to the spinning blue wheel permanently. In this case it allows the user to save (but not exit the application), and activating different cells appears to work - you just can't see the change except by the GoTo box top-left. 
If I debug and comment out the line, the code proceeds as normal to the end and still gives the blue wheel and screenupdating false experience, but allows successful save. Reopening the file allows you to continue as normal.

I'm completely lost, wonder if anyone can help please?
Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]:
Just got an application error: 
[image: ErrorMsg]

Automation error: client disconnected from object invoked.

Looked into this, and possible cause was a recalculate during macro execution. So, I disabled that during the macro running and will see how it goes (so far working, but errors are intermittent).

```
Application.Calculate = xlCalculationManual 'turns it off
Application.Calculate = xlCalculationAutomatic 't
```

Other possible causes are apparently page break insertion, which I am doing... But I couldn't see anyone explain that part.

Will update again when I know more.

```
Public Sub InsertArea()

'Dimension variables
Dim SR As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim PB1 As Integer
Dim w As Worksheet

'Set current worksheet
Set w = ActiveSheet

'Find the first cell in the row the user initiated the command from
Set Rng = ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1)


'NEW PAGE

'Check for page height breach

'Assign PB1 to current row
PB1 = Rng.Row

'Reset i to 1
i = 1

'Loop how many extra blank rows you want below the bottom spec on a page
Do Until i = 17

    'If there's a page break below row i
If w.Rows(PB1).Offset(i, 0).EntireRow.PageBreak <> xlPageBreakNone Then

    'Copy blank row
    w.Range("A1000:A1006").EntireRow.Copy

    Rng.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    'Insert page break just above the new area
    w.Rows(PB1).Offset(4, 0).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    'MsgBox Rows(PB1).Offset(4, 0).Address

    Exit Do

Else

    'Increment i to prevent infinite loop
    i = i + 1

End If

Loop


'INSERT NEW AREA

'Copy blank new area
ActiveWorkbook.Names("Temp_NewArea").RefersToRange.EntireRow.Copy

'Paste (insert) that line by shifting cell down, so target cell remains in the new blank row
Rng.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp

'ASSIGN NEW AREA WITH A NEW NAME

SR = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Spec1").RefersToRange.Address


'ADD THE NEW AREA TO SPECIFIED_RANGES

'Add that specified range to string SR, comma separated
SR = SR & ":" & Range("Quote_End").Offset(-3, 1).Address

'Create/Overwrite (by default) Specified_Areas range using string SR
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "Specified_Ranges", "=" & SR

Rng.Offset(-5, 1).Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You should fully qualify all your Rows, Ranges and Cells, also abstain from using Activate and Select where possible.. Excel will automatically ascribe the Range, Cells or Rows to whatever is sheet is active if you don't qualify them...

Comment: Good point well made, but that is half the problem - I never know which cell the user will initiate the sub from, but it does need to work. I asked similar previously and a helpful guy said I could put activecell into a range right at the start and refer to that range thereafter, which I did. Sheet references I can add though, thank you will try it.

Comment: Just a side note: `Dim i, j, PB1 As Integer` is declaring `i` and `j` as Variants, and `PB1` as an Integer. If you want to declare those all as Integers, you need to write `Dim i as Integer, j as Integer, PB1 as Integer`

Comment: Thank you, I thought I'd fixed that everywhere but thanks.

Comment: Sorry guys still no go. I've done those things and Excel is still crashing on me. I just feel lucky I can save, close and reopen and it's all still there...

Comment: Possible fix: the sheet "Template", where the range "Temp_NewArea" is located, is hidden. So, I added lines to unhide and rehide that worksheet surrounding the copy-paste operations. Maybe, just maybe, could this have caused the errors?